# Writing EJS View helpers

Tags: backbone.js, ejs, jst

I have a rails-backbone project that generates jst.ejs templates.

I'd like to include some view helpers within there, but I'm having a helluva time figuring out how to include either EJS or JST functions into that template file. If anyone could offer a very quick explanation of how to include a very basic function so that it can be read by an ejs.jst template I'd be very appreciative.

I've tried hacking into JST & EJS, plus just using bare javascript functions, but nothing is bringing any joy. Example attempt below:

Example:

```
# helpers.js.coffee
console.log('yes, this file is being called from the app')
helloWorld: () ->
  console.log "Hello, world!"

# app/assets/javascripts/backbone/templates/project/new.jst.ejs
<%= helloWorld() %>
```

(Returns uncaught referenceError)

Any ideas appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to attach that to `window`, since coffeescript puts closures `()` around each `.coffee` file.  A good example of how to deal with scoping issues is any popular js/coffee utility, like [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/).  He uses `var root = this` and `exports` to conform to CommonJS practices and get his `_` function out into the world where it can be used globally.

The book [CoffeeScript: Accelerated JavaScript Development](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript) has a chapter (chapter 4) on this very topic, as well as it's just a damn good book on CoffeeScript.  It explains a lot of where the modern world is at javascript-wise.